# How to monitor memcached statistics on windows?

Tags: windows, memcached, statistics

What's the easiest method people have found to monitor memcached on Windows? One method I've tried, which works decently:

telnet into the memcached port (11211) and enter the "stats" command. You'll get back a listing like this:

```
stats
STAT pid 2816
STAT uptime 791
STAT time 1225918895
STAT version 1.2.1
STAT pointer_size 32
STAT curr_items 10
STAT total_items 10
STAT bytes 122931
STAT curr_connections 1
STAT total_connections 5
STAT connection_structures 4
STAT cmd_get 20
STAT cmd_set 10
STAT get_hits 0
STAT get_misses 20
STAT bytes_read 122986
STAT bytes_written 187
STAT limit_maxbytes 1073741824
```

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP Memcached module also includes [a script](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/apc/trunk/apc.php?view=markup) that will display the stats in summary, and also graph form, as well as being able to view individual cached items. If you are already using PHP & memcache on windows, it's an almost drop-in solution.

Comment: The above link to script is not valid.

Comment: fixed link to PHP/Pecl repository.

Comment: The link goes to the APC monitoring script. The memcache script is here: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/memcache/trunk/memcache.php?view=markup

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Evident Software's](http://www.evidentsoftware.com/) ClearStone for [memcached](http://support.evidentsoftware.com/entries/444446-monotoring-memcached-using-clearstone-s-rest-based-open-data-interface)

Answer (score 1):

[phpmemcacheadmin](http://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/) is another free PHP app to monitor your memcached cluster, that I find a lot nicer than the script that comes with the PHP extension.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with memcached on windows and found this to be one of the main drawbacks.  It's surprising better tools have not appeared but I guess it's a case of not asking for whom the bell tolls...